# Benchmark vs Solver - same data, different result

Tags: optaplanner

Currently, we are implementing timetable planning with optaplanner - overall works great! But we are trying to do some improvements on how our solver works - try to use different algorithms etc. So we used benchmark with simple config: common heuristic phase, and than HILL_CLIMBING, LATE_ACCEPTANCE and TABU_SEARCH and this are results

Benchmark:

```
HILL: 0hard/-5medium/-5soft
LATE_ACCEPTANCE: 0hard/-5medium/-126soft
TABU: 0hard/-7medium/-4soft
```

At this where is starting to be tricky - I'm coping solver configuration and using the same data set and I have very different results:

Solver with the same dataset:

```
HILL: 0hard/-11medium/-7soft
LATE_ACCEPTANCE: 0hard/-5medium/-121soft
TABU: 0hard/-11medium/-18soft
```

So it seems that only LATE_ACCEPTANCE is close to benchmark - but others are way off - any idea why  its behave like that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both the solver and benchmark use the default, `REPRODUCIBLE` environment mode, might it be caused by different termination conditions?

Note that even if you use the same time-based termination, it may not be fully reproducible due to context switching. To make sure every run with the same configuration ends up with exactly the same score, you can use a [step-based termination](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#stepCountTermination).

Please check the INFO-level logging; each phase reports there the best attained score and the number of steps it took.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did what you mention and set up termination to 60000 steps - but still, there are differences.
I will try to debug a little bit more - maybe I have some wonky constraint.

Comment: If you suspect some of your constraints might not be deterministic, try running the solver in the `FULL_ASSERT` mode. A non-deterministic constraint may lead to score corruption, which is no longer just about consistency between a solver and a benchmark, but about correctness.